# nuget push "Data unprotection failed"

Tags: mono, nuget, osx-elcapitan

I'm using nuget on OS-X El-Capitan and mono. Up till now I've had no problems, but I just tried to do a push and I get an error:

```
$ nuget pack xxxx.nuspec
Successfully created package 'xxxx.x.x.x.nupkg'

$ nuget push xxxx.x.x.x.nupkg
Data unprotection failed.
```

I tried updating to the latest (3.3.0), but I get the same error. Mono version 4.4.0.0, XBuild engine version 14.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38712) that was introduced in Mono 4.3 and affects Mono 4.4.

If you have encrypted information stored in your NuGet.Config file that was added when you were using Mono 4.2 or earlier and you upgrade to Mono 4.3 or higher then Mono cannot decrypt that information. Mono needs to be changed to be backward compatible and handle encrypted data in the NuGet.Config file created by older versions of Mono. This was a problem that reared its head in Mono 4.2 and was fixed but seems to have occurred again in Mono 4.3 and above.

By setting your api key again you have re-encrypted the data so it will now work with Mono 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems like something was wrong with my API key for some reason. I did

`nuget setApiKey <my-api-key>`

and then it worked again. Not really sure why it stopped working in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with `nuget push` being unable to decrypt the api key properly. The way I fixed this was to pass the api key into the `nuget push` like:

```
mono nuget.exe push <.nupkg file> -ApiKey <apiKey>
```

RE accepted answer, I got this issue immediately after setting my api key so this issue goes beyond upgrading Mono version.